# Почему в админке voyager(Laravel) Multilanguage добавляется текст (ru) , изменятся но не удаляется?

Tags: laravel-5.8

делал так https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/core-concepts/multilanguage

По умлчанию английский, так вот английский удается, редактируеться,  и т.д а вкладка ru тоже самое но не удаляется

Всем привет, такая проблема, 
удаляю текст на русской версии , сохраняю и захожу текст по новой на месте если его заменить на другой то заменится но чтобы удалить полностью не получается. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо!